# How to create CA + 2 Certificates *with XCA* - For Host-to-Host IPSec authentication (No AD)

Tags: windows, security, certificate, authentication, certificate-authority

*(This is a question about using `XCA`, not `openssl`, and **[this](https://superuser.com/questions/1816744/how-can-i-configure-remote-desktop-access-from-a-specific-laptop-to-my-workstati)** is my motivation)*

**I created CA, Server, and Client certificates:**

- Within XCA, do I need to create these certificates differently?
- Does each certificate have an exact required list of Key Usage & Extended Key Usage *(e.g. all the necessary with no extra)*?

  - The client certificate has Key Usage `Certificate Sign` and it doesn't look good.

---

**Steps performed:**

1. **I installed [XCA](https://www.microsoft.com/store/productId/9N9K02V7XR1B?ocid=pdpshare) from the Microsoft Store:**
2. **I read the [Creating certificates with XCA](https://docs.fortinet.com/document/fortigate/6.2.15/cookbook/320832/creating-certificates-with-xca) from Fortinet and created:** 
    [image: Screenshot1]

   1. **CA:** `RDP_CA`
   2. **IPSec Server:** `WS_RDP` 
       *The workstation I want to access by RDP* 
       [image: Screenshot2]
   3. **IPSec Client:** `PAW_RDP` 
       *The only privileged client that should not be denied* 
       [image: Screenshot2]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How should I generate a self signed SSL for an intranet server, following these specific requisites?](https://superuser.com/a/1618151/529800). For `keyUsage` and `extendedKeyUsage`, please see answer [OpenSSL CA keyUsage extension](https://superuser.com/a/1248085/529800), with the v3 profiles for server and client under section _Non-CA Certificates_. For the client cert, `keyUsage` _`certificateSign`_, is a [CA-only](https://certificate.nikhef.nl/medium/policy/cps-medium-2.0-alpha-20010924/node151.html) `keyUsage` - only CAs/ICAs sign certs

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How should I generate a self signed SSL for an intranet server, following these specific requisites?](https://superuser.com/questions/1617564/how-should-i-generate-a-self-signed-ssl-for-an-intranet-server-following-these)

Comment: @Amit The first answer I linked to has all the steps you need to generate these correctly via `openssl` directly _(if XCA doesn't use `openssl`, it's included with [OpenVPN](https://openvpn.net/community-downloads/))_, and the [`openssl.cnf`](https://github.com/JW0914/Wikis/blob/master/Scripts%2BConfigs/OpenSSL/openssl.cnf) linked to in that prior first link already has all the required `keyUsage` and `extendedKeyUsage` correctly configured - you'd simply follow the steps in the answer as to what lines in that linked to `openssl.cnf` need to be customized in a text editor like VS Code.

Comment: @JW0914 , it is not `certificateSign` KU; It is "Certificate Sign" that functions just as a name in the GUI. In the extension it is `keyCertSign` KU. You can see it in my answer to this question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the way:

1. **Install XCA from Windows Store:** 
    *(as of 24/11/2023, v2.5.0 uses OpenSSL v3.1.2.1 from August 2023)* 
    [image: Screenshot1]
2. **Prepare a clean USB Stick for XCA database** → **Run XCA**
3. **Create a new database on the USB Stick: `Home.xcd`** 
    *The database is password protected, so it is necessary to choose one for future use* 
    [image: Screenshot2]
4. **Tab: *Templates*** 
    *XCA has four default templates for any arbitrary, non-specific use case*

   1. `[default] Empty template`
   2. `[default] CA`
   3. `[default] TLS_Client`
   4. `[default] TLS_Server`
5. ***New tepmlate* & *Change template* → *Edit XCA template* dialog** 
    *For IPSec certificates, I generated three new templates*

   1. `IPSec_CA_Template` *(inherited from 4.2)*
   2. `IPSec_Client_Template` *(inherited from 4.3)*
   3. `IPSec_Server_Template` *(inherited from 4.4)* 
       [image: Screenshot3]
6. **Tab: *Key Usage*** 
    *Select Key Usage (KU), Extended KU (EKU), and critical (optional)* 
    [image]

   1. **CA:**

      ```
      keyUsage=critical,digitalSignature, keyCertSign, cRLSign
      ```
   2. **Client:**

      ```
      keyUsage=critical,digitalSignature, keyEncipherment
      extendedKeyUsage=critical,clientAuth
      ```
   3. **Server:**

      ```
      keyUsage=critical,digitalSignature, keyEncipherment, keyAgreement
      extendedKeyUsage=critical,serverAuth
      ```
7. **Tab: *Subject***

    [image: Screenshot5]
8. **Tab: *Netscape*** 
    Unselected all and deleted the comment

---

*Once the customized templates are ready - This is the start point, for any new certificate*

**Create New Certificate**  
 *I adhered to the **[Creating certificates with XCA](https://docs.fortinet.com/document/fortigate/6.2.15/cookbook/320832/creating-certificates-with-xca)** manual of Fortinet for the creation of the certificates but with the customized templates from section 5. Since the customized templates contain all the data, including `Subject` and `Extensions`, it is necessary to click `Apply All` instead of `Apply Extensions` as written in the manual. Example for Server Certificate:*

[image]

***[For Client / Server certificate. Not for CA]** 
 (2nd thing after tab `Source`) The only thing that is not in the template is the `X509v3 Subject Alternative Name`. It should be entered specifically with the `hostname` and the `domain` of the entity for whom the certificate is issued. 
 Since it is a DHCP-enabled environment, fixed IPs are not assumed, and instead, a `hostname.domain` syntax is used. Refer to the **appendix** for information about configuring local-domain.*

[image]

---

**Resultant V3 Profiles:** 
 *Here are the X509v3 extensions (in compare with this **[reference](https://superuser.com/questions/738612/openssl-ca-keyusage-extension/1248085#1248085)**)*

- **CA:** *(The reference has also: `authorityKeyIdentifier`)*

  ```
  basicConstraints=critical,CA:TRUE
  keyUsage=critical,digitalSignature, keyCertSign, cRLSign
  subjectKeyIdentifier=hash
  ```
- **Client:** *(The reference has also: `authorityKeyIdentifier`, `nonrepudiation` (KU))*

  ```
  subjectAltName=critical,DNS:DESKTOP-KGXWQ2R.home
  extendedKeyUsage=critical,clientAuth
  keyUsage=critical,digitalSignature, keyEncipherment
  subjectKeyIdentifier=hash
  basicConstraints=critical,CA:FALSE
  ```
- **Server:** *(The reference has also: `authorityKeyIdentifier`, `nonRepudiation`(KU))*

  ```
  subjectAltName=critical,DNS:DESKTOP-24JFXST.home
  extendedKeyUsage=critical,serverAuth
  keyUsage=critical,digitalSignature, keyEncipherment, keyAgreement
  subjectKeyIdentifier=hash
  basicConstraints=critical,CA:FALSE
  ```

- Based on the comments below, `authorityKeyIdentifier` *"is usually not mandatory"* and `nonRepudiation` *"is not used for any network protocol"*.

---

**Appendix: *Local Domain***

For the local domain `home` I had to configure my router (that accepts on that field only `a`-`z` and `-` chars):

[image]

To verify whether the computer is within the `home` local domain, open `cmd.exe` and enter:

```
ipconfig /all
```

As desired:
[image]

Comment: EKUs `serverAuth` identifies a server as a server and server only, whereas `clientAuth` identifies a client as a client and client only - not specifying those EKUs allows a MITM attack to occur. I user Sophos UTM and haven't used Fortinet, but this is standard across VPN server and client certs. If the firewall appliance is also decrypting and re-encrypting packets for packet inspection, the main appliance CA likely also requires DNS `127.0.0.1` in the SAN [`subjectAltName`] profile.

Comment: @JW0914: A client won't be able to impersonate the server regardless of EKUs, because the client's certificate has a subjectAltName that does not match the server's name. It's only OpenVPN where certificate name checking is left as an afterthought – usually not the case for IPsec.

Comment: @u1686_grawity , at this moment, only my Server certificate has a subjectAltName and I am not sure that I determined it properly: The IPs are dynamic, no domain, etc. What is the proper values for subjectAltName on each certificate?

Comment: @Amit In general, a server's SAN should have its IP and/or DNS _(please see [2.2](https://superuser.com/a/1618151/529800) - email shouldn't be specified on a server cert)_, whether local or FQDN. It will always have a local domain name of `<hostname>.<localdomain>`, where the hostname is from the machine running the server and local domain being set by the router

Comment: @u1686_grawity , see my answer Resultant V3 Profiles: Are the missing items important? Are there extensions that it is better to remove? *...for IPSec purpose*.

Comment: I'm not 100% sure about what Windows' IPsec implementations need (I've mostly dealt with RouterOS and strongSwan), but: 1) CAs do not use subjectAltName at all (instead subjectKeyIdentifier is their "alternate" way). 2) For hosts, `subjectAltName=email:...` (which would be completely wrong for a TLS server) is not particularly right for an IPsec host either; it should probably be a `DNS:` or `IP:` type name (or both). 3) `nonRepudiation` KU is only relevant to _document_ signing; it is not used for any network protocol (IPsec would primarily use digitalSignature, I believe).

Comment: 4) `authorityKeyIdentifier` is usually not mandatory – it's an alternative way to link the certificate to its issuer (child aKI = parent sKI); if it's omitted, the traditional process (child 'Issuer' field = parent 'Subject' field) will be used, which is perfectly fine as long as you keep CA 'Subject' unique (i.e. as long as you don't re-use the same 'Subject' for a new CA with a new keypair).

Comment: @u1686_grawity Router OSes do make use of a SAN for the main CA of the firewall appliance. For example, Sophos UTM requires the loopback IP to be specified in a SAN for its master CA, as it's required when using transparent packet inspection where the firewall appliance decrypts SSL/TLS packets, scans them, then re-encypts them with the appliance's master CA, forwarding them on to the arbitrary host. This came up because the OP referenced Fortinet, implying this was being setup on a firewall appliance.

Comment: @JW0914: Hmm, that...doesn't quite make sense for TLS in general, I guess it's a Sophos-specific thing? Given that it's _transparent_ inspection, the TLS client wouldn't be expecting to see the appliance's IP in certs – it would still be expecting to see a SAN that matches the original URL.

Comment: @u1686_grawity It's because Sophos UTM's web filtering is able to modify and remove information from packets based on regex rules configured in the WebUI _(it's an enterprise-level UTM router OS)_, so it has to re-sign modified packets with the UTM's master CA - I can't recall the specific reason the loopback IP has to be in that CA's SAN, but it has to do with web filtering IIRC

Comment: @JW0914: That still makes zero sense. Doesn't matter what the web filter is doing – the HTTPS client isn't going to care about the filter's own IP in the SAN, especially when it doesn't even *know* that filtering is done.

Comment: @u1686_grawity This was stated clearly somewhere on Sophos' site prior to them completely redoing their site several years back, and I can no longer find it; eventually we'll have an answer though: [What is the purpose of the loopback IP in one of the UTM CA's SAN?](https://community.sophos.com/utm-firewall/f/general-discussion/143032/what-is-the-purpose-of-the-loopback-ip-in-one-of-the-utm-ca-s-san)